# mysql update query in java code not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

In mysql, I have a INVENTORY table where in I am adding `num_of_items` given by user in gui text field, to previous `num_of_items` present in mysql. I had written a query in my java code as follows.. but it's not updating my INVENTORY table..

```
try {
    st2 = conn.createStatement();
    rs=st2.executeQuery("select order_num,prod_name_in_order,num_of_items_in_order,cost_order from ORDER_DUP where order_num='"+ord_num+"'");
    int column=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

    int j=0;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=column;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(rs.getObject(i)+"\t");
            product_name1 = (String) rs.getObject(2);
            x1 = rs.getInt(3);
            //int x=Integer.parseInt(num_of_items.trim());

        }
        product_name[j]=product_name1;
        x[j]=x1;
              j++;
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
        st2.executeUpdate("update INVENTORY set num_of_items=num_of_items+'"+x[k]+"' where product_name='"+product_name[k]+"'"); //st2.close();
    //conn.close();
    System.out.printf("invy");

}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.printf("error in updating inventory table(YES)");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please help me out.. i am not getting whats wrong!!! 
THANKS.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, please post it including the complete stack trace if there is one.

Comment: No i am not getting any errors.

Comment: On your executeUpdate statement, have you verified that the variables are resolving to what you think they should?

Comment: Thanks all:):) i got it!!!     i forgot to increment j. that i edited now.. its working fine.

Comment: Would you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put single quotes around the variable value you are inserting with `x[k]`.

you query should be as follows:

```
"update INVENTORY set num_of_items=num_of_items+"+x[k]+" where product_name='"+product_name[k]+"'"
```

Comment: It worked with single quotes around x[k] though its integer value.

Answer (score 0):

First, narrow down the root cause of your problem, have you tried to print out the final statement String and run the command in your database?

```
System.out.println("update INVENTORY set num_of_items=num_of_items+'"+x[k]+"' where product_name='"+product_name[k]+"'");
```